# Suddenly error ObjectSetting.java file after importing existing project on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, performance, android-activity

I'm making a Auto SMS sender app on android,

Last time my app is working fine, but suddenly I've to delete the project form my eclipse, for this I wanna again import this project,
After importing this project my app is not working, showing lots of error on Object file. 
Please check the screenshot http://prntscr.com/75v2cg

Here is my code

```
package com.example.serviceexample.model.object;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ObjectSetting extends Object implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int setting_id;
private String setting_name;
private String setting_value;

public int getSetting_id() {
    return setting_id;
}

public void setSetting_id(int setting_id) {
    this.setting_id = setting_id;
}

public String getSetting_name() {
    return setting_name;
}

public void setSetting_name(String setting_name) {
    this.setting_name = setting_name;
}

public String getSetting_value() {
    return setting_value;
}

public void setSetting_value(String setting_value) {
    this.setting_value = setting_value;
}

public ObjectSetting() {
    this.setting_id = 0;
    this.setting_name = "";
    this.setting_value = "";
}

public ObjectSetting(String name, String value) {
    this.setting_id = 0;
    this.setting_name = name;
    this.setting_value = value;
}

public ObjectSetting(int id, String name, String value) {
    this.setting_id = id;
    this.setting_name = name;
    this.setting_value = value;
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not getting where is that problem, can you please tell me? @Blackbelt

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the java build path . Installed jre needs to be reset in eclipse project properties. As you can see its showing error for java.io and String Class itself .

Comment: Im trying but can't  solve it. How ill build  tge patH? Or install jre?

Answer (score 0):

Frist of all Check your Eclipse preferences. **window -> preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs** . The installed Jre you're using should be marked there. Also check your project's build path: Right click on the **project -> Properties -> Java Build Path**. then check in the "libraries" folder whether the JRE System Library is present and if not add it using **"Add library"->"JRE System Library"**  and then select the correct one from an installed JDK (Alternate Jre).